# $_SESSION - how long will it keep around?

Tags: php

I am a little confused about the session management in PHP.  A lot of focus in the docs is devoted to the magic PHPSESSID cookie.  I program Ajax and am actually thinking of getting rid of cookies.  I understand that I can do so in the php.ini file.  It also seems possible to suppress the PHPSESSID by means of a simple ini_set("session.use_cookies",0) at the top of my login script.  Don't get me wrong, I do want sessions.  My Ajax hand-shakes will, where required, POST the session id.  From the cookie-centric docs, one just gains the impression that all session expiry handling is done via the time stamp on the cookie.  I am unclear on how exactly a timestamp of a cookie can prompt the server to expire the session cache over a stateless connection?  Put another way, in a cookie-less setup, how can I instruct the server to clean down the session cache after a while?  Would I still be calling session_set_cookie_params?  Seems quaint...

If I understand well, then I should call sessionID(sid) and check the return for "" to make out whether "sid" is dead.  Correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[session.cookie_lifetime](http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) influences the *expires* parameter of the cookie that session_start() sets. It's  like `setcookie(<sessionname>, <sessionid>, time()+<session.cookie_lifetime>, ...)`. It advises the client not to use that cookie after `time()+<session.cookie_lifetime>` (but it can of course remove it earlier, not accept it at all or ignore the "expires" parameter altogether).
The session id is used to select the "right" session data. I.e. if a request does not contain the correct session id the session data is not available to the php script.
If only that single client knows the session id (as it should be) and throws away the cookie that contains the session id the session data is unreachable. Unreachable but still present on the server.

When a script invokes session_start() there is a chance that the garbage collection is started, see [session.gc_probability](http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.gc-probability) and [session.gc_divisor](http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.gc-divisor).
Then the flat-file session handler loops through all files in the directory specified by [session.save_path](http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.save-path) and checks the "last modified time" (mtime). If that timestamp is older than now-[session.gc_maxlifetime](http://docs.php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) the file is removed (unless this file corresponds to the current session id, in which case it doesn't matter how old the file is).
That takes some time and is therefore not performed on each call to session_start().

I.e. there can be session files on the server that are older than both session.cookie_lifetime and session.gc_maxlifetime.
session.cookie_lifetime signals the client that there is no need to store the cookie/id after x seconds.
session.gc_maxlifetime signals the session mechanism that there is no need to keep the data after x seconds.
But as long as the data remains on the server it *can* be accessed if the respective session-id is sent.

Comment: Thank you again, Volker.  What I read into this is that somehow the $_SESSION is assured (?) to hang around longer than the cookie. How is this done?  My trouble is that I want to live w/o the cookie and I want to explicitly control the life span of the $_SESSION cache.  How do I do this?  And how am I supposed to check that $_SESSION's still valid (given a session id)?

Comment: gc_maxlife and cookie_lifetime are independent parameters, from that perspective it's not _guaranteed_ that the data survives longer than the respective cookie. | Make sure gc_maxlife is big enough so that php will never remove the session files before _you_ want them to expire. After session_start() check an element of $_SESSION (e.g. $_SESSION['validUntil']), if it's not there the session id was never valid or the gc removed the file. If it is there compare the value to time() or something similar.  Or.... write your own session handler, http://docs.php.net/session.customhandler

Comment: Bingo!  Custom handler happens to be the easiest thing to do for me.  I worked out yesterday that I need to store the PHPSESSID in the user row of the database to morph a stateless connection into a stateful connection.  I can therefore easily recover my user context by recovering a row WHERE sessionID = $_POST['sessionID'].  Which means I might as well give up on all that session stuff and generate just some random key myself.  Here I rewrite again...

Comment: Most complete answer I have found so far on SO. After reading this it filled in a lot of gaps for me. Thanks @VolkerK

Answer (score 1):

The standard is 1440 seconds (24 minutes) on the most systems.

But you can change the system var 'session.gc_maxlifetime' to set it for your needs.

Comment: Ok, this baffles me.  I have so far used cookies and used session_set_cookie_params to set some arbitrary expiry.  How does session_set_cookie_params sync the cookie expiry with that of the server $_SESSION cache?  Surely it cannot call ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime") because that affects the entire script, not just the PHPSESSID?

Comment: If you really want to use a cookieless session system, you always have to sent the session id through the GET parameters. I don't know the exact server side session management system, but PHP saves a text file for each session. Those are stored by the name of the session id. I think in those files PHP also stores the last "visit" of a session user. If that time has expired the maxlifetime, than the session file will be deleted. Something like that, I guess, is done by PHP.

Comment: I just checked it on my system. I have a session id with the value "4bam43v5e2o2j6pcbro57b0jer246rqd" and the file is names "sess_4bam43v5e2o2j6pcbro57b0jer246rqd". In this file, there is only the serialized $_SESSION array as content. So I think PHP manages the expiration by the "last modified time" of this file.

Comment: It makes sense but cannot work like this when the session cookie has a lifetime greater than session.gc_maxlifetime.  The server may than receive a PHPSESSID from the client 1sec after it cleared out the $_SESSION, which is now unrecoverable.  Yet the docs suggest that the only sanity check you need to do for sessions on the server side is a simple isset($_COOKIE('PHPSESSID'))...  This can't be right.

Comment: I don't get the issue? What would not work? The deletion of files. If you sent a session id to late and than run the session_start() function you will simply have an empty $_SESSION array, just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check the lifetime of the Cookie is to view the Cookie related to your website in the browser (under Preferences/settings).

Comment: Even if you use a cookie, the session cookie will not expire after some time, but only if you close the browser. The expiration is handled server side.

Comment: Well that's precisely the question.  What's the meaning of the cookie expiry stamp (set via session_set_cookie_params) if the server handles its expiries according to session.gc_maxlifetime?  That means that the server may be receiving PHPSESSIDs for expired $_SESSION vars.  And how am I supposed to detect this?